# javascript row data comparison for asp.net grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datagridview

I need to compare two columns data for every row and the first column data value should not be greater than the second one. If the given condition is valid then I've to get total of the values in the third column.

I've not implemented javascript for grid view. This is my first time. Please give me some idea how to perform it.

```
<asp:GridView ID="tblEmployment"
    runat="server"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MALE EMP">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <input type="number" id="inputMaleEmp" min="0" value="0" runat="server">
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FEMALE EMP">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <input type="number" id="inputFemaleEmp" runat="server" min="0" value="0">
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SHIFT">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <input type="text" id="inputShift" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TOTAL">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <input type="number" runat="server" id="inputTotalEmp">
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Here value of `inputMaleEmp` should be greater than `inputFemaleEmp` and if that is valid the total should be displayed in `inputTotalEmp` and `inputShift` should not be `null`. How can I do this using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%= tblEmployment.ClientID %> input').change(function () {

            var value1 = 0;
            var value2 = 0;
            $(this).closest('tr').find('input').each(function (index, element) {
                if (index === 0) {
                    value1 = parseInt($(this).val());
                } else if (index === 1) {
                    value2 = parseInt($(this).val());
                } else if (index === 2) {
                    if (value1 <= value2) {
                        $(this).val(value1 + value2);
                    } else {
                        $(this).val("");
                    }
                }
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```